# I need to create a PayPal "Pay Now" button that will recognize the total price based on selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, paypal, calculator

I have a simple form. It has several checkboxes. I use this script to automatically add and display the total value of the checkboxes that were clicked:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
function getTotal(){
var form=document.theForm;
var inputs=form.getElementsByTagName('input');
var length=inputs.length;
var total='0';

for(i=0;i<length-1;i++){
  if(inputs[i].type == 'checkbox'){
  var checked=inputs[i].checked?1:0;
    if(checked){
    var value=inputs[i].value.split("~~")[0];
    total += value;
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById('totalspan').innerHTML="Total price will be: $"+total
total='0';
}

</script>
```

I have a Paypal "Pay Now" button, but it does not recognize the value. When you click the button, it will just come up as $0, because there is nothing linking it to the form. So, how do I make a Pay button that will know what the price is, based on the total value of the selected checkboxes? I tried to explain this as easily as possible, but I am new to HTML and script and have little knowledge of how they work.

Here is the Pay Now button script:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="harterzach10@yahoo.com"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services"/>
 <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post the Pay Now button code as well?

Comment: don't know how paypal works, but does it work client-side? Can't someone change the $ values that will be sent to Paypal? I'd guess this would be all server-side

Comment: @zen I posted the code for the pay now button.

Comment: what if some one change the amount from the client side? if then, where should we verify the amount is equal to the predefined one?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an extra field to that paypal form.  I don't know where that JavaScript is in relation to your page, but if you post the whole HTML code, we can help you further.

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="PRICE GOES HERE" />
```

Comment: what if some one change the amount from the client side? if then, where should we verify the amount is equal to the predefined one?